# Access Google Calendars within my domain

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I have integrated Google APIs into my system and I want to be able to add events to calendars belonging to others in my company. I am currently able to add events to my calendar because it is a publicly shared calendar however I was wondering if there was a way to add events to other calendars in my domain and not have all of the calendars be publicly shared. Can you use ad administrator account to do this? Is this possible?

thanks,

Eric

Comment: Using OAuth2 you can have the other people authenticate your application and give you access to there calendars.

Comment: wouldnt you need a client id, secret, and that stuff for all the users then?

Comment: Clientid and client Secret identify your application to Google, you only need one per application.  This is an example but it uses Google Analytics API - http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/  might give you an idea.